# Capacitor Identification for speed board

Tags: capacitor

I've got a Speed Control Board that a Cap fell off of.  It came out of a pair of Andis Clippers my wife uses for Dog Grooming.  It plugs into 120V outlet. I can't find any info on what the specs, besides the 470uF, are on it.  The Cap goes right in the middle of the board where the solder pads are.  It is not through hole soldered.  The board has a power button in the middle and an increase speed button above it and decrease speed button below it.  I have ordered a new board but I need this functional until it comes in if possible.  Any other info just let me know and I'll do what I can.

[image: Closer pic of Cap][image: Bottom of Cap with plastic base][image: Side of Cap with plastic base]
[image: Cap I need ID'd with plastic base]
[image: Speed Control Board missing the Cap][image: Another view of Speed Board]

Answer (score 0):

Your capacitor is rated at 6v, 470uF, The package type A.

You can purchase a new one at this link, or google for another one that meets your specifications:
https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=PCE3771TR-ND

Refer to the following diagram for SMD electrolytic capacitors:

[image: Electrolytic Cap SMD]

[Image from Digikey Blog](https://www.digikey.com/en/blog)

Comment: So as long as the Capacitance is the same I can use a higher voltage, right?

Comment: @Masted85 yes, but stick to what the manufacturer uses when ordering a new one. Higher voltage rated capacitors are more expensive and have additional parasitics. This is why for 3.3v-5v boards you will see a lot of 6.3v capacitors.

Comment: I have some here at work but if I can't find a 6V I just needed to know what I could do to bandaid it until the new board comes in.

Comment: @Masted85 what do you have on hand?

Comment: The lowest voltage I could find is 25V 470uF

Comment: @Perfect. Use that. Feel free to update your post with the results. Is this the only damage that the controller underwent?

Comment: It is.  My wife told me the power was working intermittently so I took it apart and cleaned it.  As I went to put it back together it just fell off.

Comment: @ Masted85 I would test the controller when you've replaced the capacitor. Make sure to make good connections to the power lines; I think that is what was causing it to behave inconsistently but I may be wrong.

Comment: Will do.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Welcome. Hope all works out. If so a checkmark is much appreciated ;)

Comment: A is the lowest MTBF class and thus cheapest G is very high reliability due to hours at high temp